# Array Syntax Error

Tags: python, sorting, arraylist, syntax-error

It says that I have a syntax error. But I don't see whats wrong. It's on the line where it says a.append. I'm so confused. I apologize i'm a newbie. I need some help. I'm pretty sure I have more than one. But the first one is on a.append(0)

```
def invalidsyntax(a):
    if max(a)>20:
        print("The highest number is in position", a.index(max(a)))
        a.remove(max(a))
    if min(a)>5:
        print("The smallest number is", (min(a))), index.append(min(a)
        a.append (0)
    if min(a)>5
        a.sort(['a'])
        sum('a') / float(len('a')
        a[2]
        a[-3]
```

Comment: You forgot the colon after the last `if` statement.  And in the print statement, you left off a couple closing parentheses (and you have an extra one in the middle of it).

Comment: Also, `sum('a')` cannot possibly work... as can't `a.sort(['a'])`

Comment: I just fixed that but there's still that syntax error.

Comment: You are missing a ) on the previous line, flagging as off-topic

Comment: schwobaseggl what should I put there. I need to get that fixed but I don't know what to put.

Comment: You need to check out a tutorial and then proofread your code. Missing colons and parentheses will cause errors.

Comment: @zbush548 as pointed out, make sure your parentheses match. `a.sort()`,  `sum(a)` and `len(a)` will work if `a` is actually a list.

Comment: Since you're a newbie, here's a tip: don't paraphrase error messages, but include them fully in your posts. It makes the job of others (who sacrifice their spare time to help you) much easier. In general, reading [ask] is a must.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL;DR: you are missing at least one parenthesis, and how you place the parentheses correctly depends on whether you are using Python 2 or Python 3.

---

Count your parentheses:

```
print("The smallest number is", (min(a))), index.append(min(a)
     ^                          ^   ^ ^^^
     |                          |   |_|||
     |                          |______||
     |__________________________________|
```

In either Python 2 or Python 3, the syntax error is the missing parenthesis for `index.append(min(a))`.

---

However, just supplying that parentheses doesn't entirely fix your problem.  Python 2 and Python 3 will interpret the resulting line slightly differently. Suppose you write the following:

```
print("The smallest number is", (min(a))), index.append(min(a))
```

In Python 2, you have a `print` *statement* provided with two expressions: the tuple `("The smallest number is", min(a))` (the parentheses around `min(a)` are redundant) and the call to `index.append`. The value of each expression is printed on the same line, separate by a space. Since `index.append` always returns None, the output is

```
# Assuming min(a) returns 9
("The smallest number is", 9) None
```

In Python 3, you have an expression statement, consisting of a call to `print("The smallest number is", min(a))` (again, the parentheses around `min(a)` are redundant) and a call to `index.append`. `print` is a *function* in Python 3. Now the output is just

```
The smallest number is 9
```

and the value of the expression is the tuple `(None, None)` (the return values of the two functions.)

Comment: So **Mr down-voter**?..Where the heck is your **comment**???...

Comment: Wait what? I didn't down vote it. I meant to upvote it. Iron Fist. I'm sorry.

Comment: @IronFist The post is a _typographical_ error which is explicitly mentioned as off topic by this sites help page. These questions should be answered in the comments and flagged/closevoted. Also, don't assume everyone on this site is a man

Comment: @Natecat .. It's not about *assuming everybody to be man* .. but kindall following the rules here...If you have downvoted, then post a comment as why so.

Comment: @Iron Fist there are no rules saying that a down vote necessitates a comment, and especially in cases in this the reason for the downvote is very apparent

Comment: @Natecat I felt the situation was a little more complicated than a simple typo. The exact problem depends on whether you are using Python 2 (missing a trailing `)` on the second expression passed to the `print` statement) or Python 3 (an extra `)`terminates the function call early *and* two missing `)`, one to terminate the call to `append` and one to terminate the call to `print`).

Comment: Python 3 also has the possibility of having an expression statement consisting of two calls, one to `print` and one to `append`. Keeping in mind that the return value of `append` is always `None`, and therefore rarely interesting to print, that actually makes the most sense.